# Why does kafka producer throw java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: kafka-producer

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to run this sample kafka producer code in scala SBT, But I am alwasy getting this error. I can see the class is available at kafka-clients of version 0.11.0.0 .

I am new to SBT and KAFKA both and I have spent whole day today to just be able to produce a data. Can you please help. Thanks

Github: www.github.com/axeish/kafkawatcher

my built.sbt is as follow:

```
name := "KafkaWatcher"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.0"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

and my Producer code is this:

```
import java.util

import java.util.Properties import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._

object producer extends App {

  val props = new Properties()   props.put("bootstrap.server", "localhost:9092");   props.put("acks","1")   props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")   props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  val topic="kafka"
  for(i<- 1 to 50) {
    val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, "key"+i, "value"+i)
    producer.send(record)   }

  producer.close()

}
```

And,
I am getting following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>   org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)

Comment: its working for fine with the same sbt, only thing it is `bootstrap.servers` not `bootstrap.server` - see configs here https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs I would recommend trying from sbt console.

Comment: can you tell me how to run through sbt console?